# Quantile in For Loop returning incorrect results

Tags: r, for-loop, quantile

I am fairly new to R, not sure what's causing quantile code, to return two different results. When put in a for loop to calculate for all columns, it returns incorrect quantile values vs when run individually per column, the results are different (and correct).

**Sample data:**

```
set.seed(1)

dt_sample <- data.frame(
  group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 10),
  var1 = rnorm(30),
  var2 = rnorm(30),
  var3 = rnorm(30)
)
```

**Code for individual column:**

```
var1_quantile <- dt_sample %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(quant25 = quantile(var1, probs = 0), 
            quant50 = quantile(var1, probs = .25),
            quant75 = quantile(var1, probs = .5),
            quant100 = quantile(var1, probs = 1))
```

**Results:**
group quant25 quant50 quant75 quant100
             
A       -1.47 -0.542    0.221     1.60
B       -2.21 -0.0461   0.129     1.51
C       -1.99 -0.654    0.404     1.12

**For Loop code, for all columns:**

```
library(dplyr)

for(i in dt_sample[,c(2:4)]){
  
  loop1 <- dt_sample %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarize(quant25 = quantile(i, probs = 0), 
              quant50 = quantile(i, probs = .25),
              quant75 = quantile(i, probs = .5),
              quant100 = quantile(i, probs = 1))
  
  print(loop1)
}
```

**Results:**

group quant25 quant50 quant75 quant100
             
A       -2.21  -0.435   0.257     1.60
B       -2.21  -0.435   0.257     1.60
C       -2.21  -0.435   0.257     1.60

group quant25 quant50 quant75 quant100
             
A       -1.38  -0.388 -0.0566     1.98
B       -1.38  -0.388 -0.0566     1.98
C       -1.38  -0.388 -0.0566     1.98

group quant25 quant50 quant75 quant100
             
A       -1.80  -0.537   0.114     2.40
B       -1.80  -0.537   0.114     2.40
C       -1.80  -0.537   0.114     2.40

Column #2 is var1 which for group A is -1.47, -0.542, 0.221, 1.60 in individual calculation, but when added another column, it is -2.21, -0.435, 0.257, 1.60

Could anyone please help review? I inserted the same code in for loop parenthesis with "i" defined to pick all columns from df_1. What's causing this?

Comment: Hi @Rashltls, could you please provide a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Used the data frame another person here suggested. The commands work fine when I calculate quantiles individually per column but put it in a for loop, the results change

Answer (score 0):

**solution using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

dt[, as.list(quantile(.SD, probs = c(0, .25, .5, 1), na.rm = T)), by = group]
```

**just some sample data**

```
set.seed(1)

dt <- data.frame(
  group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 10),
  var1 = rnorm(30),
  var2 = rnorm(30),
  var3 = rnorm(30)
)
```

**results**

```
   group     0%     25%     50%  100%
1:     A -1.805 -0.3721 0.05117 2.402
2:     B -2.215 -0.1491 0.25658 1.980
3:     C -1.989 -0.6587 0.07718 1.125
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing but this is not working in a loop. Without the loop, I am able to do quantile and group by the specific column. Let me share a reproducible example with your data frame.

Comment: The results change even if I use the code you suggested in for loop.